# Cómo guardar una variable en un archivo txt y después utilizar su valor

Tags: c#, bucle-for

Muy buenas comunidad, quiero guardar una variable para que itere en un ciclo como acomulador.

y que cada vez que cierre y ejecute el programa está variable tenga el último valor almacenado en el txt agradezco su atención y colaboración.

```
var variable = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++)
{    
   variable = variable * i;    
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué has investigado y qué has intentado? Recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes implementar un método para leer y escribir la variable a un archivo. En el `script` que te adjunto:

- `void WriteVariable(string fileName, int variable)` escribe al archivo `fileName` el entero `variable`.
- `int ReadVariable(String fileName)` lee la variable guardada en `fileName`. Si `fileName` no existe o no contiene un entero válido devuelve `1`.

Una posible solución sería:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        const string fileName = "variable.txt";
        int variable = ReadVariable(fileName);
        
        Console.WriteLine("Valor de variable: {0}", variable);

        for(int i = 1; i <= 5 ; i++)
        {    
            variable = variable * i;    
        }

        WriteVariable(fileName, variable);
    }
    
    private static void WriteVariable(string fileName, int variable)
    {
        File.WriteAllText(fileName, variable.ToString());
    }

    private static int ReadVariable(String fileName)
    {
        int variable = 0;
        try
        {
            using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(fileName))
            {
                variable = int.Parse(reader.ReadLine());
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            variable = 1;
        }

        return variable;
    }
}
```

Puedes ejecutar el código online acá https://onlinegdb.com/eEJUNNTUN. He modicado el ciclo para que empiece en `1` porque si empieza en `0` el valor de variable siempre será nulo.